# Add information from a data frame from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame (`jan2020`) of bicycle services, where the origin and destination stations are mentioned as follows:

```
Origen_Id Destiny_Id #data frame A
        2         52
       93         10
```

In another data frame (`stations`), I have the station's Id, name, latitude and longitude, and other information.

```
id Nombre  Latitude   Longitude
 2  Name1 20.666378  -103.34882
 3  Name2 20.667228    -103.366
 4  Name3  20.66769 -103.368252
```

I would like to create a data frame like this,

```
Origen_Id Destiny_Id   Lat_Orig    Lon_Orig     Lat_Des    Long_Des 
        2         52  20.666378  -103.34882 some number some number
```

I tried to do it with  a `for-loop` but it's not efficient, another thought was to

```
jan2020$Index_Id <- match(jan2020$Origen_Id, stations$id)
```

However, this only tells me the index of the station in the data frame `stations`, and I'm not sure how to create a new column with the information I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let two data as `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "Origen_Id Destiny_Id 
 2             4
 3            2 ", header = T)
  Origen_Id Destiny_Id
1         2          4
2         3          2

df2 <- read.table(text = "id Nombre Latitude Longitude
2  Name1 20.666378 -103.34882
3  Name2 20.667228 -103.366
4  Name3 20.66769  -103.368252", header = T)
  id Nombre Latitude Longitude
1  2  Name1 20.66638 -103.3488
2  3  Name2 20.66723 -103.3660
3  4  Name3 20.66769 -103.3683
```

Then , desired result `df3` may done by

```
df3 <- cbind(df1, df2[match(df1$Origen_Id, df2$id),3:4], df2[match(df1$Destiny_Id, df2$id),3:4])
names(df3) <- c("Origen_Id", "Destiny_Id", "Lat_Orig", "Lon_Orig", "Lat_Des", "Long_Des")
df3
  Origen_Id Destiny_Id Lat_Orig  Lon_Orig  Lat_Des  Long_Des
1         2          4 20.66638 -103.3488 20.66769 -103.3683
2         3          2 20.66723 -103.3660 20.66638 -103.3488
```

Comment: this help me a lot! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Merge it twice, once on *Origen_Id* then on *Destiny_Id* with suffixes:

```
merge(merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Origen_Id", by.y = "id"),
      df2, by.x = "Destiny_Id", by.y = "id", suffixes = c("Ori", "Des"))

#   Destiny_Id Origen_Id NombreOri LatitudeOri LongitudeOri NombreDes LatitudeDes LongitudeDes
# 1          2         3     Name2    20.66723    -103.3660     Name1    20.66638    -103.3488
# 2          4         2     Name1    20.66638    -103.3488     Name3    20.66769    -103.368
```

(using [Park's data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70210934/680068))